# linq orderbyAscending?

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

Hi I am using the following to sort results of a datatable returned by a tableadapter

```
 Dim spots = myDataTable.Where(Function(t) t.UserID = 1).OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Title)
```

The thing is, I also need to OrderByAscending the very same datatable. But as far as I see, it is not giving it as an option. I am sure there is a way to sort it ascending. Can anyone show me how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) will order in ascending order.

```
Dim spots = myDataTable.Where(Function(t) t.UserID = 1) _
                       .OrderBy(Function(t) t.Title )
```

Or, if you need to sort by a second value, use [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx)

```
Dim spots = myDataTable.Where(Function(t) t.UserID = 1) _
                       .OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Title ) _
                       .ThenBy(Function(t) t.OtherField )
```